# Перестало работать меню onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android, activity, меню, toolbar

Пример взял с сайта https://habrahabr.ru/post/270121/ 
Ссылка на исходник готового приложения https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

После того как вставил этот код, перестал работать обработчик меню в тулбаре, меню видно но не как не реагирует на нажатия кнопок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может можно использовать, что-то кроме onOptionsItemSelected?

Исходник:

```
public class LastActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener{

private static final float PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR  = 0.9f;
private static final float PERCENTAGE_TO_HIDE_TITLE_DETAILS     = 0.3f;
private static final int ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION              = 200;

private boolean mIsTheTitleVisible          = false;
private boolean mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = true;

private LinearLayout mTitleContainer;
private TextView mTitle;
private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);

    bindActivity();
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, 0, View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void bindActivity() {
    mToolbar        = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mTitle          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview_title);
    mTitleContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout_title);
    mAppBarLayout   = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_appbar);
}

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {
    int maxScroll = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
    float percentage = (float) Math.abs(offset) / (float) maxScroll;

    handleAlphaOnTitle(percentage);
    handleToolbarTitleVisibility(percentage);
}

private void handleToolbarTitleVisibility(float percentage) {
    if (percentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR) {
        if(!mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.VISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleVisible = true;
        }
    } else {

        if (mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.INVISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleVisible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void handleAlphaOnTitle(float percentage) {
    if (percentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_HIDE_TITLE_DETAILS) {
        if(mIsTheTitleContainerVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitleContainer, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.INVISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = false;
        }

    } else {

        if (!mIsTheTitleContainerVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitleContainer, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.VISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = true;
        }
    }
}

public static void startAlphaAnimation (View v, long duration, int visibility) {
    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = (visibility == View.VISIBLE)
            ? new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)
            : new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);

    alphaAnimation.setDuration(duration);
    alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menu_share) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, FavorActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".LastActivity">


<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Favorite" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо или назначить тулбар экшнБаром, чтобы он хватал нажатия методом активити так:

```
toolbar = ...;
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Или повесить свой слушатель нажатий на тулбар так:

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Menu CLICKED!");
            return false;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, то что нужно))

Comment: @Artsait, пожалуйста) Кстати, вы можете не только принимать ответы, но и голосовать за них)